# Performance of filtering by cumulative relationship property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get all vertices up to a certain maximum cumulative weight (distance) from a specific node. The query

```
MATCH route = (p1:ReferencePlace) - [roadlist:EROAD*..5] - (p2:ReferencePlace)
WITH p1, p2, route, roadlist, 
    REDUCE(sum=0.0, road in roadlist | sum + toFloat(road.distance)) as totaldistance
WHERE totaldistance < 300
AND p1.name = "Paris"
RETURN p1, p2, totaldistance
```

produces the right output. This uses the E-road data example imported like [here](https://gist.github.com/lassewesth/2d6402a43ee1126b3452ba4d2a9aa4bd#file-eroad-data-import-cypher-statement). It returns all places which are less than 300 km from Paris.

The problem is, that this only works for limited number of hops `EROAD*..5]`. For `EROAD*]` it "hangs" (I don't know whether it would finish in any reasonable amount of time). This is because Neo4j first finds all possible routes and then filters them. So it makes sense that the number of routes gets infeasibly large even for a small graph like this.

In theory it would be no big deal to implement a BFS algorithm from scratch which just gathers all relevant vertices as long as long as the cumulative distance is smaller than the threshold and *only* visits the relevant ones. But I'm wondering whether there's a Neo4j way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem might be cycles in the graph, as suggested [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/performance-of-filtering-by-cumulative-relationship-property-distance/15238).

I ended up using the `algo.shortestPath.deltaStepping.stream` algorithm

```
PROFILE MATCH (start:ReferencePlace {name:'Paris'})
CALL algo.shortestPath.deltaStepping.stream(start, 'distance', 3.0, {relationshipQuery: 'EROAD'})
YIELD nodeId, distance
WHERE distance <= 800
RETURN algo.asNode(nodeId) AS destination, distance
```

This seems to be doing what I want, even though conceptually it's not a straight-forward approach to my problem. Will see how it scales for larger graphs.

Comment: can you help with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666188/how-to-get-all-parent-nodes-of-a-particular-node-based-on-id