# How to get all parent nodes of a particular node based on ID

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to fetch all 3rd level nodes(4,5,6 and 7 in below pic) and its relationships along with its parent node details
In the below example:

- If I send `ID : 7` then I should get node info of `3` and `1
- If I send `ID : 4` then I should get node info of `2` and `1

[image]

How can I get parent node details? Please help

> EDIT:
>   I am trying query to get nodes, edges and immediate parent details. Nodes and edges I am getting but with parent I am getting big list of nodes. Not sure why
>
> `Match (n)-[r]-() OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:ParentNodeType)<--(child)  return n,r,COLLECT(parent) as parent`

[image]

Comment: can you show exact query which you are trying.  do you have parent, child two different nodes and what is relation name b/w them?

Answer (score 0):

So If you want to get all nodes of parent then use below query

```
Match (n)-[r]-() OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:ParentNodeType)<-[r1*]-(child)  return n,r,COLLECT(parent) as parent
```

As you mentioned in comment you are looking for 3rd level parent so you can give level number also whatever you want to get. Please see below query for specific level

```
Match (n)-[r]-() OPTIONAL MATCH (parent:ParentNodeType)<-[r1*3]-(child)  return n,r,COLLECT(parent) as parent
```

and as per my understanding you do not need to write this long query. check below query if you are getting your required result

```
MATCH (p)<-[r*3]-(c)  return p,r,c
```

Comment: I have updated the question hope it makes sense now

Comment: I think this should work. did you try this query what result you are getting using this query?

Comment: If you see my updated question I am not passing any id's. I want to fetch all 3rd level nodes and its relationships along with its parent node details

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical path query. If you link it to both child and root, you only have to retrieve a single path. Below I assume that you pass `myid` as a parameter and that you have linked the nodes using  `:HAS_CHILD` relationships

```
// the path pattern
MATCH path=(root)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(child)  
// limiting the search
WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_CHILD]->(root)
      AND child.ID = $myid

//returning the results
RETURN path

or 

// return the IDs, except the last one, because it is the node you started from
UNWIND nodes(path)[..-1] AS node
RETURN node.ID AS parent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (n:Child)
WHERE n.id = "ID"
WITH n, [(n)<-[:CHILDREN*]-(Root) | Root] as ancestors,  [(Root)<- [:CHILDREN*]-(n) | Root] as descendants
RETURN n, ancestors, descendants

Where n -> The node that we used for fetching data
      ancestors -> Represents list of Parent nodes
      descendants -> Represents list of Child nodes
      CHILDREN -> Is the relation-ship between Parent and Child (change accordingly)
      Root -> It is the label for accessing Parent (change accordingly)
```

**This query is capable of fetching all the parent and child nodes of the provided node**